# help with iperf and infiniband and multiple NIC

Tags: networking, benchmark

I have two Dell servers in a rack in my server room:

- **RHEL 7.9 x86-64** and **iperf-2.0.13-1.el7.x86_64**
- hostnames are `A` and `B`
- each has

  - 1 10GbE intel nic, having 2 ports
  - 1 1Gbps intel nic {traditional} having 2 ports
  - 1 mellanox infiniband card
- my network naming is

  - em1, 10GbE port 1
  - em2, 10GbE port 2
  - em3, 1Gbps port 1, **static ip 192.168.1.1 / 255.255.255.0**
  - em4, 1Gbps port2
  - ib0, mellanox infiniband 100 gbps, **static ip 192.168.2.1 / 255.255.255.0**
  - `A` is 192.168.x.1 and `B` is 192.168.x.2 where x = 1 for 1Gbps and x = 2 for infiniband
  - I can `ping` between each and also `scp` between either on the infiniband 192.168.2.x subnet.

On `A` if I simply do `iperf -s` and on `B` I do `iperf -c 192.168.1.1` is works and says 942 mbits/sec.  But on `B` if I do `iperf -c 192.168.2.1` I get no route to host.

How do I use `iperf` in this scenario to see the transfer speed over specific network interfaces?  Specifically my `ib0`?  And eventually over my `em1` 10GbE when I get that set up?

Comment: Some info that would be helpful is the ifconfig for the network interfaces, the routing table (netstat -nr), and the output from ibstat. Each of these for both hosts.

Answer (score 1):

Can you get the [latest from sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf2/)?  I'd suggest git checkout 2-1-1-dev and build that.

To your question, one can bind to an interface using the % convention, e.g. iperf -c 192.168.1.1%ib0

See the [man page](https://iperf2.sourceforge.io/iperf-manpage.html), NOTES section:

Binding is done at the logical level (ip address or layer 3) using the -B option and at the device (or layer 2) level using the percent (%) separator for both the client and the server. On the client, the -B option affects the bind(2) system call, and will set the source ip address and the source port, e.g. iperf -c  -B 192.168.100.2:6002. This controls the packet's source values but not routing. These can be confusing in that a route or device lookup may not be that of the device with the configured source IP. So, for example, if the IP address of eth0 is used for -B and the routing table for the destination IP address resolves the output interface to be eth1, then the host will send the packet out device eth1 while using the source IP address of eth0 in the packet. To affect the physical output interface (e.g. dual homed systems) either use -c % (requires root) which bypasses this host route table lookup, or configure policy routing per each -B source address and set the output interface appropriately in the policy routes. On the server or receive, only packets destined to -B IP address will be received. It's also useful for multicast. For example, iperf -s -B 224.0.0.1%eth0 will only accept ip multicast packets with dest ip 224.0.0.1 that are received on the eth0 interface, while iperf -s -B 224.0.0.1 will receive those packets on any interface, Finally, the device specifier is required for v6 link-local, e.g. -c [v6addr]% -V, to select the output interface.